# Clip parts/boxes of a background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a main container, content wrapper called `#outside`. This div has a background image, full width and height. Let's call it `background image with blur effect`.

Inside the `#outside` div I have the `#inside` div, again full width and height. This div has also a background image. Let's call it simply `overlay background`.

Inside the `#inside` div I have small content boxes, `.box`. Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/henrichro/gUc7E/

What I'd like to know, if there is a way that on the place of the `.box` boxes to have the `overlay background` clipped so the `background image with blur effect` will be visible? But only inside the `.box` boxes. The coordinates of `.box` boxes can differ from page to page, so they have no static coordinates. If possible, which is that way?

I've played around with JavaScript, I'll copy that here even if I know it's a total mess.

```
var topleft;

$(".box").hover(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var top = offset.top;
    var left = offset.left;
    console.log(top);
    console.log(left);
    var t = $('#inside').css({
        'clip':'rect(5px 40px 45px 5px)'
    });
    console.log(t);
}, function() {
    $(this).css({'opacity':'1'});
    $(topleft).css({'opacity':'1'});
});

var offset = $('.box').offset();
var top = offset.top;
var left = offset.left;
console.log(top);
console.log(left);

var img = { x1: '100%', x2: 717, y1: 216, y2: 436, url: "images/bg-blur.jpg" };

$(".box").css({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  background: "url('" + img.url + "')",
  backgroundPosition: "-"+left + "px " + "-"+top + "px"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't perfect (I've hard coded the margins to remove and had to remove the margin on your inner item).  But, it should get you started.

```
$(".box").each(function() {
    var offset = $(this).position();
    var top = offset.top +143;
    var left = offset.left + 133;   
    $(this).css({
      background: "url('http://s24.postimg.org/bjouleih1/bg_blur.jpg')",
      backgroundPosition: "-" +left + "px -" + top + "px"
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/gUc7E/2/

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for a "clip/crop" method but also this is a good start point for me and I appreciate your effort. Just a note, on full screen backgrounds `var offset = $(this).offset();` could be an option also and getting rid the `+143` calculations. I'm taking this as a good solution.